# Set default values of a webform element from a field on a user account

Tags: webforms

On a user account I have field **field_hourly_rate** which is a price field (I can also use a number field for it) and I am trying to set the field as default value of an element for a webform placed on the user account page.

I have tried **[current-user:field_hourly_rate]**, **[current-page:query:field_hourly_rate]**, **[webform_submission:user:field_hourly_rate]**, **[webform_submission:source-entity:field_hourly_rate]**, **{{ webform_token('[current-page:query:field_hourly_rate]') }}**

None of them worked.

**EDIT:**

This is how I finally was able to solve this: I installed the module *Current Page Entity Tokens*, https://www.drupal.org/project/current_page_entity_tokens and it made tokens available for the user who owns the profile being viewed and so I was able to get the token **[current-page:user:field_hourly_rate]** I added the token in the webform computed token element and pulled the value from the user account. Meanwhile because I wanted to make computations with the value the price field didn't work because it was coming bundled with the currency so I changed to a number field and everything worked.